unable to figure out why my logic is incorrect , simple function to find trading stop loss and take profit using price zones with 1:3 target
I cant figure out why the values being given are not correct, as well as the risk to reward calculations being incorrect as well, i'm not sure what i'm getting wrong.
Essentially to find the closest take profit to 1:3 as possible, given an entry. The stop loss would be the immediate previous zone start for buy and end for sell.
`
# Define the zones list as provided
zones = [
    (5039.5, 5114),
    (5182, 5221),
    (5254, 5275.5),
    (5288.5, 5304.5),
    (5335.75, 5353.25),
    (5365.5, 5386),
    (5419.5, 5457.5),
    (5528, 5604)
]

def buy(price):
    stop_loss_candidates = [zone[0] for zone in zones if zone[0] < price]
    
    stop_loss = max(stop_loss_candidates) if stop_loss_candidates else None
    
    take_profit_candidates = [zone[0] for zone in zones if zone[0] > price]

    take_profit = None

    for tp in take_profit_candidates:
        if stop_loss is not None and tp - price >= 3 * (price - stop_loss):
            take_profit = tp
            break

    return stop_loss, take_profit

def sell(price):
    stop_loss_candidates = [zone[1] for zone in zones if zone[1] > price]

    stop_loss = min(stop_loss_candidates) if stop_loss_candidates else None

    take_profit_candidates = [zone[1] for zone in zones if zone[1] < price]

    take_profit = None
    found_take_profit = False

    for tp in take_profit_candidates:
        if stop_loss is not None and price - tp >= 3 * (stop_loss - price):
            take_profit = tp
            found_take_profit = True
            break
        if found_take_profit:
            break

    return stop_loss, take_profit

def calculate_buy_risk_reward(price, stop_loss, take_profit):
    if stop_loss is None or take_profit is None:
        return None
    risk = price - stop_loss
    reward = take_profit - price
    if risk == 0:
        return None
    return reward / risk

def calculate_sell_risk_reward(price, stop_loss, take_profit):
    if stop_loss is None or take_profit is None:
        return None
    risk = stop_loss - price
    reward = price - take_profit
    if risk == 0:
        return None
    return reward / risk

# Test prices
test_prices = [5321, 5300, 5200, 5100, 5500, 5280, 5242, 5219, 5204, 5441.75]

# Run buy and sell functions for each test price and calculate risk-reward ratio
results = []
for price in test_prices:
    buy_result = buy(price)
    sell_result = sell(price)
    buy_risk_reward = None
    if buy_result is not None:
        buy_risk_reward = calculate_buy_risk_reward(price, *buy_result)
    sell_risk_reward = None
    if sell_result is not None:
        sell_risk_reward = calculate_sell_risk_reward(price, *sell_result)
    results.append((price, buy_result, buy_risk_reward, sell_result, sell_risk_reward))

# Output the results
for price, buy_result, buy_risk_reward, sell_result, sell_risk_reward in results:
    print(f"Price: {price}")
    print(f"  Buy Result: {buy_result}, Risk-Reward Ratio (Buy): {buy_risk_reward}")
    print(f"  Sell Result: {sell_result}, Risk-Reward Ratio (Sell): {sell_risk_reward}")
    print()


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
